# prevent memory access reordering in a lockfree algorithm

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86-64, atomic, lock-free

I have a tree structure which is used in a lockfree algorithm. I want to make sure that the compiler or the processor does not reorder the reads and writes to this structure.
This is the node structure:

```
struct node
{
    unsigned long key;
    std::atomic<struct node*> child[2];
    std::atomic<bool> flag;
};
```

This is how the nodes are created:

```
struct node* createNode(unsigned long key)
{
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->child[0] = NULL;
    newNode->child[1] = NULL;
    newNode->flag = false;
    return(newNode);
}
```

CompareAndSwap to add or remove nodes:

```
static inline bool CAS(struct node* parent, int which, struct node* oldChild, struct node* newChild)
{
    return parent->child[which].compare_exchange_strong(oldChild,newChild,std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```

An example logic performed on the tree structure:

```
funcCalledByMultipleThreads(struct node* node,unsigned long key)
{
    L1. foo(); //a function which does not affect the value of node's flag
    L2. flag = node->flag;
    L3. if(flag) // I want this check to be done after the call to the function foo() returns
    {
        CAS(node,0,someOldValue,newOldValue);
    }
}
```

Here the function `foo()` does not affect the value of the atomic variable `node->flag`. But I do not want these instructions to be executed out-of-order. Specifically, I do not want `L2` to be executed before `L1`. But can the compiler or the processor (multicore)  reorder the lines `L1-L3`?

Since the variable `node->flag` is atomic, I assume that, I do not need any extra `fence` instructions. Is my assumption valid?

Comment: You're fine as long as the atomic accesses to flag are acquire/release or stronger.

Comment: Thank you.  And how do I check if the atomic access to flag is acquire/release.  Node->flag.is_lock_free() returns true. Does that mean it is safe to assume it's access will not be reordered?

Comment: Atomic variables use sequential consistency implicitly by default (imo a bad decision but here we are) - you can specify it explicitly if you use read/write calls. You can leave it as is, but specifying acquire/release memory consistency can dramatically improve performance on some CPU architectures.

Comment: You say I can specify it explicitly.  But do I have to? What can go wrong if I don't?

Comment: as I said the default is sequential consistency which has performance overheads on some architectures.